# gvim - open dir under cursor in new tab

Tags: file, vim, directory, tabs, text-cursor

I have a library file which has bunch of files and 'dir' paths. I am trying to find out some way to open dir listing in new tab so I can take a look at all of the files of that dir and open I need to.

vim has option to open file under cursor (goto file)

> ```
> <Ctrl-w>gf
> ```

Not sure how to open dir under cursor in new tab to see all of the file list of that directory and open any of that file in new tab

Comment: Have you tried using `<c-w>gf`? It works for me. You can also do `:tabedit <c-r><c-f>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I expect your “path” isn't obvious to Vim. It needs to look distinguishably like one.

Here’s a demo of the problematic and working case (obvious path needed):

```
% mkdir mydir
% touch mydir/myfile
% vim foo
# insert text: mydir/
<C-w>gf
E447: Can't find file "mydir/" in path
# change text to: ./mydir
<C-w>gf
okay, nerdtree (or dir chooser) in new tab!
```

Comment: thanks for pointing out .. there was problem with path itself ... Now "tools/gls/stdcell/" and "tools/gls/stdcell" both works as long as I update the PATH in vim.